# How to make a secure communication for NodeJs server and React.js as client (static hosting) using EC2 as a middleman for routes/forwarding request?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, socket.io

How do I make a secure communication for NodeJs server and React.js as client using EC2 as a middleman for routes/forwarding request?

I am using Socket.IO. And I want to use EC2 server as a middleman for routing/forwarding all requests from nodejs server to react.js client.
Also including the AWS Certificate.